# parallellization in python multiprocessing

Tags: python, multiprocessing

I need to do parallelization in Python for my existing code and I am blocking in one for loop. 
I used `multiprocessing.process` but it's freezing the computer.

```
import multiprocessing

def func(pos,r,h,grid):
    for i in arayb:

        l= L(r,g, p[i,:],h) #process need to be parallelized (L is function in another file)
        p = multiprocessing.Process(target=func)
        p.start()
        p.join()
        print('l',l)
if __name__ == '__main__':
    lock = Lock()
```

When I am using `if __name__ == '__main__':` above like:

```
import multiprocessing
from source.RUN import* # imported main file 

def func(pos,r,h,grid):
    for i in arayb:

     l= L(r,g, p[i,:],h) #process need to be parallelized (L is function in another file)
if __name__ == '__main__':
    lock = Lock()

        p = multiprocessing.Process(target=func)
        p.start()
        p.join()
        print('l',l)
```

Then it will not go to `multiprocess.Process`.

So please give me appropriate way to do `l = L(r,g, p[i,:],h)` in parallel for `for i in arrayb`.

I have 13 to 14 processes like `l = L(r,g, p[i,:],h)` that need to be parallelized, so give me guidance about one, then I can make the others parallel.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your first example is freezing the computer because you're recursively calling `func` in new processes. That's going to quickly use up all your CPU/memory. Your second example is just creating one process that iterates over `arayb` and calls `L` without any concurrency, so you're not getting any performance boost.

What you want to do is execute `L` concurrently across multiple processes, but without spawning so many processes that you bog down your system. You can use [`multiprocessing.Pool`](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.pool.multiprocessing.Pool) for that:

```
import multiprocessing
# L must is imported or defined somewhere up here...

if __name__ == '__main__':
    p = multiprocessing.Pool()  # Creates a pool with as many workers as you have CPU cores
    results = []
    for i in arayb:
        results.append(pool.apply_async(L, (r, g, p[i,:], h)))
    p.close()
    p.join()
    for result in results:
        print('l', result.get())
```

Comment: thanks for your ans I have to import this file (multiprocessing.pool) to different file and that's why I need function anyway.. so with function how can I write this code???

Comment: @dbr You can move everything inside of the `if __name__ == "__main__"` block into a function, as long as you make sure you only call that function from code that's *also* protected by `if __name__ == "__main__":`. Failure to do that will cause breakage on Windows.

Comment: thanks for revert but if I am adding the function in this code and running it then  it will not go inside the if__name__=="__main__":,so in which way I can add the function outside the if__name__=="__main__": or inside...???

Comment: @dbr Sorry, I'm not sure what you're trying to do. Are you trying to put the code that creates the pool into a function so that you can import it from some other sript?

Comment: yes.. I have a big for loop in my code and there is individual processes that I need to parallel , but when I am using pool or multiprocessing in between For loop then It will interrupt the loop that's why I have decided to make new function in new file and then give the pool there and then import that file in existing code and call the function in between the For Loop.. so I need to have function to call in another file.so give me advise what should I do? Or if you can then just provide your email..